# How can I connect shortcut keys to Button

Tags: button

I want to connect a shortcut key (ctrl + c) to a `Button` in my application. To that purpose I wrote some code using `EventHandler`. When the mouse button is clicked it's working fine, but the ctrl + c key press isn't working.

```
 EventHandler[ Button["Click"],
   {
     {"KeyDown", "c"} :>MessageDialog["This is button"],
      "MouseClicked" :>MessageDialog["This is button"]
   }
 ](*EventHandler Function is closed*)
```

Answer (score 2):

The definitions you give to `EventHandler` are only active when your selection is on its contents. An example of where the button press also works would be:

```
 EventHandler[
  InputField["Click"], {{"KeyDown", "c"} :> MessageDialog["This is button"], 
       "MouseClicked" :> MessageDialog["This is button"]}, 
 PassEventsDown -> True]
```

Where you will get the pop-up first when you press the field, and afterwards if you press c while the selection is in the input field. Notice I added `PassEventsDown` otherwise your cursor will not go into the field when you press it the first time.

If you want to have a global event that triggers when you press c, independent of where the selection is, you can add it to the `NotebookEventActions` of the notebook:

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "c"} :> MessageDialog["This is button"]}]
```

Then any press of c will trigger the event. And if you need to get back (because it gets annoying having a pop-up any time you press c for instance) you simply set the `NotebookEventActions` back to `{}`

```
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions :> {}]
```

Comment: :I eveluated code what you are mentioned,still it's not working .If you don't mine can you explain clearly.....

Comment: @subbu You'll have to be more clear in what code you evaluated and in what way it did not work.

Comment: Actually I make a cdf with a single`Button`,if I press (ctrl + c ) after open that cdf file,that coresponding `Button`action will be perform ,I want like that.